# How to show month in one datepicker based on the selection of month in another datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here is the snippet where i need to fix the requirement

Here i used jquery for datepicker

```
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes
           /base/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here i gave datepicker to choose month by dropdownlist but problem is in two fields the user can select the month but i need to restrict the month selection in "to" field because the second datepicker should show the month of "from field" itself

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker,#datepicker1").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-0:c+10",
        dateFormat: "dd - M - yy"
    });
    $('#datepicker,#datepicker1').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

Here are the two datepickers with two fieldnames "from" and "to"

```
           <li><label class="label">From:</label></li>
               <li><input name="fdate" type="text" class="sel" size="10"  
                      id="datepicker" required /><li>
               <li><label class="label1">To:</label></li>
               <li><input name="tdate" type="text" class="sel" size="10"  
                      id="datepicker1" required  /><li>
               <li ><label class="label" >Weeks:</label></li>
```

Comment: How about setting the date of datepicker1 to the value of datepicker, possibly like this `$('#datepicker1').datepicker("setDate", $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'));`  and possibly in here `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ onSelect: function(){ ##here## } });` (when the date is selected)

Comment: why not use date range http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

Below is the snippet for above requirement......

```
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-start-custom-1.10.3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-custom-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all').hide();
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "-0:c+10",
                dateFormat: "dd - M - yy",
                onClose: function(selectedDate) {
                    $('#datepicker1').datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
            $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());

            $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                yearRange: "-0:+0",
                dateFormat: "dd - M - yy"
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: u posted ur previous question's answer here.

Comment: yes... after posting this question i got answer from you so i posted that answer here

Comment: but problem is if i click on previous button then it is going to previous month.....@Lakshmana Kumar

Comment: `<style type="text/css"> .ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev { display: none; }</style>`  use this so it wil hide both buttons

Comment: ok now how can i restrict dates not to accept the "to" field less than "from" field date....

Comment: so want restrict date in to `field`?

Answer (score 0):

Small script that Iam using....try with this

```
var startDateTextBox = $('#datepicker');
    var endDateTextBox = $('#datepicker1');

    startDateTextBox.datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange : 'c-30:c',
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd", 
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                    var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
                    var testEndDate = endDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
                    if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                        endDateTextBox.datepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
                }
                else {
                    endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            },
            onSelect: function (selectedDate){
                endDateTextBox.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate') );
            }
    });
    endDateTextBox.datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange : 'c-30:c',
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",  
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                    var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
                    var testEndDate = endDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
                    if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                        startDateTextBox.datepicker('setDate', testEndDate);
                }
                else {  
                    startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
                }
            },
            onSelect: function (selectedDate){
                startDateTextBox.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate') );
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it gives you an idea...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker({
             yearRange: "-50:+20",dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',showOn: "button",changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,
                buttonImage:""+appctx``+"/images/index.jpeg" ,buttonImageOnly: true ,buttonText: "",autoSize:true ,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                 $( "#toDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate ); 
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });

        $( "#toDate" ).datepicker({
             yearRange: "-50:+20",dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',showOn: "button",changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,
                buttonImage:""+appctx+"/images/index.jpeg" ,buttonImageOnly: true ,buttonText: "",autoSize:true ,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                 $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate ); 
            },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```